# View just works with top ***

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have an issue with a view:

when i run for ex.

```
select *
from v_adresses
```

the query runs forever.

when i use:

```
select top 1000 *
from v_adresses
```

i get my 29 rows of data.

What could be the problem?

Comment: It's hard to know without intimate knowledge of the schema. At least show what v_adresses looks like. Can you get a count of the rows in that table (or view?) If it is a view you need to tell us this.

Comment: How long is 'forever'? If the logic in the view takes a long time to process, it may seem like 'forever' but its really "20 minutes". Please be more specific.

Comment: Take a look at this post https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24832/how-and-why-does-top-impact-an-execution-plan

Comment: If your view takes "forever" to return just 29 rows it needs urgent refactoring and optimization. Is it overly complex, are there missing indexes, does it *prevent* the use of indexes? Impossible to tell unless you post the view definition and the table schemas *including* the indexes

Comment: questions seeking performance help should include DDL,DML Of the tables involved along with test data..if your test data is large,try scripting out schema and stats for the table(right click database->generate scripts->select specific database objects->in next screen select advanced and choose Script statistics) and paste it in question..With this info any one repro the same issue you are facing.Otherwise it becomes very difficult to answer your question .Pasting server version also helps

Comment: Perhaps the query is so inefficient that it has to keep processing a large amount of rows even though it already found the 29 results? That's why TOP 1000 *seems* to be faster - it forces the query to stop before processing the next eg 1M rows that don't have the expected results. If even one of the result rows appeared after the first 2000 rows though, you'd lose results

Comment: Does this `select top 1000 * from v_adresses` query also take "forever"?

Comment: @Cool_Br33ze How would OP knows it returns 29 rows if it takes forever.  Would the question make any sense if select top takes forever?

Comment: @Paparazzi I was being facetious,, anyway how long does the `TOP 1000 * ` query take?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help... next time I will add more information.

The solution was to rebuild the indexes and statistics:

```
exec sp_msforeachtable "DBCC DBREINDEX('?')"
go

exec sp_msforeachtable "UPDATE STATISTICS ? WITH FULLSCAN, COLUMNS"
go
```